# How to create a d3 stacked bar chart that only iterates through columns 1 and 2 of data file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to modify my stacked bar chart to only iterate through (stack) columns 1 and 2 in my data file and ignore columns 3+ which will be used for other purposes in the chart. All the examples I've found use this function to iterate through all the columns:

```
function type(d, i, columns) {
for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
d.total = t;
return d
```

}

My CSV data file is as follows:

```
SL,Outpatient,Inpatient,Trend,Threshold
SL 1, 42, 99, -1, 100
SL 2, 23, 58, +1, 100
SL 3, 15, 74, 0, 100
SL 4, 99, 23, +1, 100
SL 5, 33, 86, +1, 100
SL 6, 38, 20, 0, 100
```

I've tried modifying the above function in pretty much any way I can think of to get the job done, but with no luck. I'm a ux designer by trade, so script isn't my strongest thing. I only want to stack the Outpatient and Inpatient columns. My first though was to try this:

```
function type(d, i, columns) {
for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length - 2; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
d.total = t;
return d
```

Alas, that didn't work. Any help with this issue or direction that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That row function (called `type`) you shared is not removing anything. It's just selecting different columns to add to the `total` property.

Personally, I'd load the CSV as it is, without deleting anything, and I'd create *another* array, filtering the original one by column. Another option is defining the columns in the stack generator. In both ways you keep all original columns, in case you need them lather. It's almost never wise *deleting* information: just choose what information will be used.

However, if you want to do that using the row function, this is how you can do:

```
function type(d, i, columns) {
  for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
    if (j > 1) delete d[columns[j]]
  }
  return d;
}
```

Here is the demo with your data, check the console:

```js
var csv = `SL,Outpatient,Inpatient,Trend,Threshold
SL 1, 42, 99, -1, 100
SL 2, 23, 58, +1, 100
SL 3, 15, 74, 0, 100
SL 4, 99, 23, +1, 100
SL 5, 33, 86, +1, 100
SL 6, 38, 20, 0, 100`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, type);

function type(d, i, columns) {
  for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
    if (j > 1) delete d[columns[j]]
  }
  return d;
}

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I believe that by *"columns 1 and 2 of data"* you are referring to "Outpatient" and "Inpatient". In that case, do `if (j > 2)`.